# MySQL SELECT QUERY same column different where statements

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I have 2 tables. Service 1 name and Service info.

I need to grab all Unique names from service name and show how many service infos are attached to it eg.

```
SELECT cs.serviceDesc as 'SERVICE', COUNT(cr.serviceId) as 'Count',
FROM consultationRequests cr
JOIN consultationServices cs on cs.serviceId = cr.serviceId 
JOIN demographic d on d.demographic_no = cr.demographicNo 
WHERE cs.active = 1  
AND cr.referalDate between '2018-11-31' and '2019-01-20' 
GROUP BY cr.serviceId
```

There is also another column in consultationRequests that has a status number between 1-4. I need to add in another column for each status and count the number of infos that are within that status WITHIN the service name.

Comment: update your question adda proper  data sample and the expected  result

Comment: I would think that you will need to group by on both columns, then you can get the information that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT cs.serviceDesc as SERVICE,
       COUNT(cr.serviceId) as Count,
       SUM(cr.consultationRequests = 1) as cnt_1,
       SUM(cr.consultationRequests = 2) as cnt_2,
       SUM(cr.consultationRequests = 3) as cnt_3,
       SUM(cr.consultationRequests = 4) as cnt_4
FROM consultationRequests cr JOIN
     consultationServices cs
     ON cs.serviceId = cr.serviceId JOIN
     demographic d
     ON d.demographic_no = cr.demographicNo 
WHERE cs.active = 1  AND
      cr.referalDate between '2018-11-31' and '2019-01-20' 
GROUP BY cr.serviceId
```